# How do I dynamically update a column in pandas with the value of the column to its left?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a series of columns that contain boolean values, one column for each month of the year. Here's a snippet of the df:
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Aeuy.png)

I'm trying to update the 2019.04_flag, 2019.05_flag, etc columns with the last valid value. I know that I can use df[2019.04_flag].fillna(2019.03_flag), but I don't want to write 11 fillna lines. Is there a means of updating the value dynamically? I've tried to use the fillna method with the ffill parameter here [df with ffill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP9N6.png), but as you can see it doesn't propagate across the row.

Comment: So you want to fill in a NaN with the last valid value in that row?

Comment: Correct, and I want to do it for every column. My columns are 2019.01_flag, 2019.02_flag....2019.12. I need to fill the Nan in each of those columns with the last valid value

Answer (score 0):

### Edited

I would look into the pandas fillna method, documentation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html). It has different methods for filling NaN -- I think "ffill" would suit your needs. It fills the NaN with the last valid entry. Try the following:

```
df = df.fillna(method = "ffill", axis = 1)
```

Setting `axis = 1` will perform the imputation across the columns, the axis I believe you want (a single row across columns).

Comment: I've tried using fillna, but that propagates values down the column, not across the row. I did the following (ls is a list with the column names I'm trying to update, btw):

df[ls] = df[ls].fillna(method='ffill', axis=0)

And my df still returns Nan values in the columns

Comment: Hm okay. A couple of cases where this could happen is (1.) if you ls list is only one column -- then the row length is 1 and cannot compare to any other value, (2.) the entire row is NaN. I think (2) may be the issue just looking at your attached snippet of your df

Comment: If you want to edit the question and add the solution you tried & the output that would help!

Comment: Sorry, first time asking a question here! I updated with a snippet of the code I used and its output.

Comment: @user1848447 See my edited answer using ```axis = 1```